# Checking wifi network in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, data-connections

I want to to store data in server with the click of a button called "save" when I press that button i want to check wifi if it is available I should be able to save data otherwise check data connection if there is no balance then I should get an error message 'no internet' otherwise save the data how can I do this?

Comment: You can check my answer: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762423/checking-if-there-is-internet-connection/39762702#39762702)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if Internet is active with wifi network connected in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240867/how-to-check-if-internet-is-active-with-wifi-network-connected-in-android)

Comment: This is not the duplicate of my question

Answer (score 3):

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

Reference link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html

You will need to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: this is not i am looking for

Comment: this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check your device is connected with wifi then use this method.

```
public static boolean isInternetConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mnetwork = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return mnetwork != null && mnetwork.isConnected();
}
```

And if you want to check your device is connected with Mobile Network Internet then use this method.

```
public static boolean isMobileInternetConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mNetwork = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return mNetwork != null && mNetwork.isConnected() && mNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
```

**Note:** Don't Forget to Add Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And I have already answered of your question.Check the link given below

[This is answer of your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240867/how-to-check-if-internet-is-active-with-wifi-network-connected-in-android/42106931#42106931)